# Pandas identify all rows in column 1 where duplicates occur in columns 2,3

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, dataframe

I am trying to drop duplicate entries from a Pandas DataFrame in Python. The DataFrame consists of vertically concatentated contents of multiple *.csv files. Here is the DataFrame:

```
print(df)

     file    TestA    TestB
  One.csv     7513   -643.1
  One.csv    15347      NaN
  One.csv      NaN     22.7
  One.csv    46321      NaN
  One.csv      NaN    156.1
  One.csv     2477     52.7
  Two.csv      417   1473.5
  Two.csv     7513   -643.1
  Two.csv    15347      NaN
  Two.csv      NaN     22.7
  Two.csv    46321      NaN
  Two.csv      NaN    156.1
Three.csv    -4341      NaN
Three.csv    34473      437
Three.csv     1349      NaN
 Four.csv       17      NaN
 Four.csv      107      NaN
 Four.csv     -931    44536
 Four.csv     6285      NaN
 Four.csv      119    34722
```

I would like to do the following:
a. something like:

```
print(
    f"Rows {[1,2,3,4,5]} of {'One.csv'} are duplicated in rows {[2,3,4,5,6]} of "
    f"{'Two.csv'}. Rows from {'One.csv'} will now be removed "
)
```

I want this result of the `print` statement:

```
Rows [1,2,3,4,5] of One.csv are duplicated in rows [2,3,4,5,6] of Two.csv. Rows from One.csv will now be removed from the DataFrame.
```

I am not sure how to identify the rows and set them up in the `print` statement.

Is there a way to identify the duplicated rows by row number of column number 1 (`FileName`)?

EDIT:
To create the DataFrame `df`, select and copy the DataFrame from here to the clipboard. Then use this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly do you want to print, but you can identify duplicated rows with `groupby`:

```
In [169]: g = df.groupby(['TestA', 'TestB'])
In [170]: g.groups
Out[170]: 
{(-4341.0, nan): [12L],
 (-931.0, 44536.0): [17L],
 (17.0, nan): [15L],
 (107.0, nan): [16L],
 (119.0, 34722.0): [19L],
 (417.0, 1473.5): [6L],
 (1349.0, nan): [14L],
 (2477.0, 52.7): [5L],
 (6285.0, nan): [18L],
 (7513.0, -643.1): [0L, 7L],
 (15347.0, nan): [8L],
 (34473.0, 437.0): [13L],
 (46321.0, nan): [3L],
 (nan, 22.7): [9L],
 (nan, 156.1): [4L],
 (nan, 156.1): [11L],
 (15347.0, nan): [1L],
 (nan, 22.7): [2L],
 (46321.0, nan): [10L]}
```

And then you can choose which ones do you want to remove

Comment: Hi, I have added to the original post what I would want the `print` output to be. I want to find a list of duplicate row numbers in the 2` *.csv` file names from the `FileName` column. In `One.csv` I would like a list that indicates `[1,2,3,4,5]` and in `Two.csv` I would like a list that indicates [2,3,4,5,6].

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to post what I have tried and hopefully it gets something going here:

1.This gives me the duplicates:

```
duplicates = df[df.columns[1:]].duplicated()
```

2.This gives me a list of the files with duplicate entries:

```
files = df[duplicates==True]['file'].unique().tolist()
```

3.This prints a message that is close to what I want, but not exactly what I want:

```
print('Rows of ' + ", ".join(["%s"]*len(files)) + 'are duplicated. These rows will now be removed from the dataframe.' % tuple(files))
```

The print statement is missing:

1. the row numbers of each file - it is missing `[1,2,3,4,5]` for One.csv
2. the row numbers `[2,3,4,5,6]` for Two.csv

If someone can find a way for these row numbers to be included in the print statement (as I had described in the original post), then that would be answer this question.

Comment: I have added further a comment to the post below explaining the lists required. I also added this to the original post. If there is any additional information required, please feel free to let me know. I would like to get some help with the printing of the row numbers (mentioned above).